# Safe to kill a process called *:etlservicemgr (LISTEN)?

Tags: port, lsof, kill-process

I am trying to serve locally to port 9001 but I get an `listen EADDRINUSE` error. When I look at the port with `lsof -i :9001` it shows the following

```
COMMAND  PID    USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    3369  Name     12u  IPv4 0x617528c251f49bb      0t0  TCP *:etlservicemgr (LISTEN)
node    7803  Name     11u  IPv6 0x617528c1ecc1133      0t0  TCP *:etlservicemgr (LISTEN)
```

What is `etlservicemgr`? Can I kill it?

Comment: What does `ps -ef | grep 3369` say? Why are you trying to use a port that is already in use? Are you the owner of the server?

Comment: Smells like TOR

Comment: @CraigWatson `ps -ef | grep 3369` leads back to my own app... whoops. Looks like it didn't exit cleanly and the process hung around. I killed it and restarted my app, which is working as expected.

Answer (score 5):

`etlservicemgr` is not the name of the process listening on port 9001. It's the name of the [IANA-registered service](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) for that port number.

```
$ grep 9001 /etc/services
etlservicemgr   9001/tcp                # ETL Service Manager
etlservicemgr   9001/udp                # ETL Service Manager
```

The name of the process appears in the first column, `COMMAND`.

We can see from your output that two processes called `node` are listening on this port (one on IPv4, and one on IPv6). And `node` is most likely a Node.js application.

Comment: Yes, you are right. With the help of @CraigWatson and `ps -ef | grep 3369`, it turns out it's my own app blocking itself from restarting.